# One UIPickerView Two Data Sources/Views works once then crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, uipickerview

I am trying to display a single UIPickerView in my app and depending on what button is selected a UIPickView will popup and populate with the relevant data for the button selected. No sure if it matters but one UIPickerView has three columns and one has two. I can get both of them to work perfectly when the are separate but the minute that I nest them into if statements it breaks.

On the third time when I select the button that fires the opposite UIPickerView it crashes and give me the error of NSRangeException and that it is trying to find the object at index 2 in an array [0...1]. My understanding is that the program thinks that there is an object in a spot in the array that doesn't exist.

I have tried the [picker reloadAllComponents] method and have it called each time the button is selected but as stated above that only works once and then it quits. The strange thing is that if I select the button that I pressed for the second set of code it works perfectly. It is when I select a button that would make the UIPickerView have to change its view that it crashes.

I am really new to iOS development and Objective C and hope that someone out there knows what I am doing wrong. I will post any code that you guys need and will post a couple samples just to understand what is going on.

Here is one of the buttons methods that sets an int to 2 and also calls the method to show the picker.

```
-(IBAction)linePopupPicker{
picker = 2;
[self pickerShow];
}
```

This code is the other method which is pretty much the same as the other (I am aware that I haven't implemented the UserDefaults into the second button yet)

```
-(IBAction)namePicker{
field  = 1;
picker = 1;
NSLog(@"The value of field is:%i", field);
NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewNameColor"] inComponent:1 animated:NO];
[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewNameFontSize"] inComponent:2 animated:NO];

[self pickerShow];
}
```

This is the method that calls the UIPickerView. I have it so that it emerges onto the view rather than being static. I thought that this would be the best place to reload the components.

```
-(IBAction)pickerShow{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 240);
pickerView.transform = transform;
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];


[tipPicker reloadAllComponents];


[UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Finally here is just a sample of the code that is used throughout the various methods that need to be called for the UIPickerView.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
if (picker ==2) {
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            UILabel *lineColorLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 44)] autorelease];
            lineColorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            NSString *lineTempColor = [colorArray1 objectAtIndex:row]; 
            //NSLog(@"The String Color Name:%@", tempColor);
            UIColor *myColor1 = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(lineTempColor)];
            lineColorLabel.backgroundColor =  myColor1;
            return lineColorLabel;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            UILabel *alphaLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,40, 44)] autorelease];
            alphaLabel.text = [alphaArray objectAtIndex:row];
            alphaLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
            alphaLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            alphaLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            alphaLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            return alphaLabel;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

else if (picker == 1) 
 {
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            UILabel *fontLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 44)] autorelease];
            fontLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            fontLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            fontLabel.text = [fontNames objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *font = [fontNames objectAtIndex:row];
            fontLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:font size:18.0];
            fontLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            return fontLabel;
        }
        case 1:
        {


            UILabel *colorLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)] autorelease];
            NSString *tempColor = [colorArray objectAtIndex:row]; 
            //NSLog(@"The String Color Name:%@", tempColor);
            UIColor *myColor = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(tempColor)];
            colorLabel.backgroundColor =  myColor;


            return colorLabel;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            UILabel *sizeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,40, 44)] autorelease];
            sizeLabel.text = [fontSizeArray objectAtIndex:row];
            sizeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
            sizeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            sizeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            sizeLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            return sizeLabel;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the data methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView { 
if (picker == 2) {
    return 2;
}else if (picker == 1) {
    return 3;
}

//return 3; 
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component { // This method also needs to be used. This asks how many rows the UIPickerView will have.
if (picker == 2) {
    if (component == 0) {
        return [colorArray1 count];
    }
    return [alphaArray count];
}else if (picker == 1) {
    if (component == 0) {
        return [fontNames count];
    }else if (component == 1) {
        return [colorArray count];
    }
    return [fontSizeArray count];
}

}
```

I hope this post provides all of the information that is need to help me get this fixed. I really appreciate it and hope that I am just missing something really simple. Thank you in advanced.

I am really new to iOS development and Objective C so this problem is really stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case 1` in the `if ( picker == 2)` switch statement has an opening brace but no closing one.

**EDIT**

```
- (void) savePickerOne {
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:[tipPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] ForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:[tipPicker selectedRowInComponent:1] ForKey:@"pickerViewNameColor"];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:[tipPicker selectedRowInComponent:2] ForKey:@"pickerViewNameFontSize"];
}
```

Comment: I added the  closing brace right above default and now I get the error "Expected identified or '(' before 'else'" on else if (picker ==1) line.  I also get the same error on the last closing bracket for that method.

Comment: yeah there's one extra there. Remove one.

Comment: I took away the extra one and the codes builds but I still get the original error from the original post.

Comment: can you provide how you implemented the data source methods?

Comment: They are arrays that I create in the viewDidLoad section below is an example.

Comment: example below? I wanted to ensure that `numberOfComponentInPickerView:` and `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` are correctly set up. Since we are talking about an invalid index, I think the error could be in those methods.

Comment: No the two data source methods I mentioned.

Comment: They are not in separate methods but rather all of them are in the viewDidLoad section. I have had the UIPickerView working using this method when it is just one it is this second set that is screwing it up. Thank you for replying so quickly!

Comment: Add it to the problem itself.

Comment: Are `tipPicker` and `pickerView` same?

Comment: And are you sure your selection defaults are not crossing the array bounds? It could be the reason. Print them out before setting.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean. tipPicker is the UIPickerView and pickerView is the UIView.

Comment: Ok. 'pickerView` is something I would choose as an instance of `UIPickerView` so the doubt. Are the selection defaults all correct?

Comment: By selection defaults do you mean the default text that each method provides for the UIPickerView? Not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: I was talking about the arguments here – `[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewNameColor"] inComponent:1 animated:NO];
[tipPicker selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewNameFontSize"] inComponent:2 animated:NO];`

Comment: You are an absolute genius. I just commented those out and guess what? It WORKS!!! Now, here is the question. Is there a way to set these defaults without have this error occur again?

Comment: Override them. Do something like this for each of them. `[pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:0 ForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"]` and then after setting you will need to synchronize it. `[pickerViewSelectionDefaults synchronize]`

Comment: Where would you override them? I tried doing this above and below the arguments in one of the methods with no luck.

Comment: Do it once in `viewDidLoad` and remove it later.

Comment: Confused. Do you mean to override all the defaults in the viewDidLoad method? If so, then what "it" do I remove later and where do I remove "it"?

Comment: the code snippet I meant. We just want to reset it once right?

Comment: My confusion lies in the fact that I am not sure where to initially set the different components before the UIPickerView for that particular set is shown. That was the reason that I had those defaults set in each of the methods. Also, where do you suggest the code snippet your provided to be placed?

Comment: You can put reset snippet in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if you want. As for saving and loading the values, you are loading them at the right place. You will have to save them when the picker is either dismissed or source is swapped.

Comment: Could I put the reset snippet in the viewdidload method? As for saving them you would put all of those arguments that are called in the individual case statements into the method that changes the source int for example? Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: I added this: NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; to the method and now I get a warning that 'NSUserDeafaults' may not respond to '-setInteger.....

Comment: NSUserDeafaults? spelling mistake?

Comment: Ok I fixed that by changing ForKey to forKey (capital letter)

Comment: It still isn't reading the values for each of the components to set the default position for each of the components.

Comment: I wish I can help quicker but it is difficult for me to diagnose without the code at hand. Since we agree this is about user defaults, I think you should take a look at [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html) or follow some tutorials online to figure what's wrong.

Comment: I agree on both fronts. I am just so happy that the basic functionality is working. You have be so great and I cannot thank you enough. I am sure you know the feeling when you have been trying to fix something for so long and then it is fixed. That is what you helped me achieve. Thank you very much and I am sure that I will be able to figure out the default problem. By the way, why did commenting out the default setting in each of the methods work?

Comment: Commenting out worked because you were sending an invalid row to the method `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` i.e. the one or more values in the defaults had an invalid value. Based on your error message, it is requesting for the 3rd row in a component with only two rows.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I think that I will have to think about where to put the default positions loading statements as having them in the method spot where they are currently is causing the app to crash.